# Master Data Services entity error

Tags: master-data-services

I'm starting to use Master Data Services and I came across something strange. When I deploy the sample models and entities and afterwards go to the Master Data Manager website, I see under "System Administration" in the left column under the Model name a tree structure of entities.
[image]

However, when I created my own model and entity (+attributes), I couldn't find the entity under the model on the left side.
[image: screenshot of my MDS website]
How can I fix this?

I suppose that is also why I get an "invalid entity" error message when trying to create members through the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this, although I'm not sure if it's really necessary to 'fix'.
When creating an entity, if you set "enable explicit hierarchies and collections" to "yes", the entity will be placed in the left-hand side tree view too.
I'm not sure if it's absolutely necessary to do so for at least one entity but it did help in my case.
Microsoft mentions the following about this ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487054.aspx ):

> From the Enable explicit hierarchies and collections list, select one of the following options:
>
> No. Select this option if you do not need to enable the entity for explicit hierarchies and collections. You can change this later if needed.
>
> Yes. Select this option when you want to enable the entity for explicit hierarchies and collections. In the Explicit hierarchy name box, type a name. Optionally, select Mandatory hierarchy (all leaf members are included to make the explicit hierarchy a mandatory hierarchy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The "strange" view is the Model View, and the entities you add from the left to the right side will be displayed in the "Explorer" view (inside the Explorer function, there is an Explorer menu as well).